# Why do people edit posts?

Tags: discussion, edits

Here is the story:

- Someone with a 42,000 reputation edited one of my answers from 2009, to fix a minor grammatical error.
- The post was an answer to a build tool suggestion, and the reviewer modified the post to add the company name, a link to the company, and a blurb.
- I guess the post came to the attention of a reviewer, but in any case, it was down-voted (due to its low quality, due to its now new commercial aspect, who knows, I might have down-voted it myself in 2016).
- I thought the answer was decent for 2009, but obviously a bit dated for 2016. I ended up deleting the answer.

But it left me wondering why does somebody with a 42,000 reputation waste time editing 8 year old posts. Is that how people get to a reputation that high rather than answering questions, which is the real value of the site?

Comment: You don't earn rep for edits after 2k

Comment: Can you point to the post in question please?

Comment: Just because you *may* have experienced an instance of a bad edit here (withholding judgement until I can see the post in question), that doesn't make editing a worthless activity. In fact, as Macro Man points out, you don't earn any points for it once you cross 2000 points. It's one of the least rewarded activities on the site, and incredibly valuable to the community.

Comment: Your title and body don't match.  Do you want to know why people edit posts or do you just want to complain about one bad edit?

Comment: "...obviously a a bit dated for 2016. I ended up deleting the answer." Well, there's one benefit to the edit.

Comment: @ Servy, I only asked one question in the post.Sorry if I do not consider adding a link to a vendor and capitalizing a word in an eight year old post with a score of 0 a valuable activity. I guess someone does.

Comment: @tony so you're confirming that the title of your question has nothing to do with what you're asking, and you just want to complain about one bad edit.  Okay.

Comment: @ Servy, again,  I only asked one question in the post. A question ends with a question mark. If it is not clear, it is the last sentence. Everything else is extraneous context.

Comment: @Tony did you even read your question title?  It ends in a question mark.  If you have entirely extraneous content in your question then remove it.

Comment: Where is it so we can vtc the question?

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim It's likely they found your post while looking for the same recommendations. Then decided to include a link to the vendor, rather than have people have to search *again* to find the correct site (which they likely had to do). I fail to see the problem with that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is that how people get to a reputation that high rather than answering questions, which is the real value of the site?

That would be exceedingly difficult. People with non-reviewed edits *don't get* reputation from editing.

People edit such questions/answers because... they're there. We allow people to edit things so that they can be *improved*. I can't say whether this particular edit constituted an improvement, but the ability to edit a post and make it better is very much a good thing. In addition to this, people can be [rewarded with badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/364217).

Comment: Even so, the site should respect an OP enough to at least let them confirm a change.  Sometimes assumptions are made that are incorrect, and edits (or even worse, closing or "duplicate marking") mangle a question so badly that it's not even what they're asking.  But oh well, the site's about making money now, not helping people.

Comment: @Manius: "*closing or 'duplicate marking'*" Those aren't edits. They're votes. And shutting down bad questions is perfectly acceptable; it is not "mangling" anything. Lastly, how many of these edits are bad? Maybe 1%? 0.1%? The site notifies you when an edit to your post has been made; just go look to see if it's good, and roll it back if it isn't.

Comment: Never said they were edits, I said they were worse (far worse actually).  However locking or redirecting questions is absolutely ruining the site.  If you're cynical, you may even suggest that "high point" people are doing it on purpose to keep others from "catching up" to their worthless score.  I agree poor edits are a relatively minor issue here.  Which makes this question (and the fact that it has -20 votes currently) a little amusing.  You all are wasting your time on trivial, gimmicky nonsense.  Just help people solve their problems and stop trying to be Internet janitors. Nobody cares.

Comment: @Manius: "*Nobody cares.*" *We* care. And no, closing questions is not "ruining the site". If the site is being ruined, it's because of *garbage* questions, things that nobody's time should be spent reading let alone closing.

Comment: Closing _good_ questions (which is subjective--and so what?) is ruining the site. Closing terrible ones isn't a big deal, but the "power" is over-used. And those who care about trivial edits are in the minority, sorry.  But feel free to delude yourself that the majority of visitors here care about closing or editing a question that was asked 1+ year ago. Fact: Majority of users here only ask/answer a single question. SO has big problems now.  Perhaps you should educate yourself instead of sweeping it under the rug?  https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: @Manius: "*Perhaps you should educate yourself instead of sweeping it under the rug?*" Have you ever heard the phrase "'data' is not the plural of 'anecdote'"? Slegers's rant is just a bunch of quotes assembled to prove his point, while simultaneously ignoring any evidence to the contrary. There are just as many people here who feel that the biggest problem is the flood of *garbage questions*. Why is Slegers right and they are wrong?

Comment: No, it's more than just "quotes", especially when you look at all the other references it's linked to, but okay--whatever.  Have fun closing useful and highly popular Q/A posts with 100's or 1000+ upvotes for whatever subjective/arbitrary and gimmicky reasons the SO kings decide upon.

Comment: @Manius: "*Have fun closing useful and highly popular Q/A posts with 100's or 1000+ upvotes for whatever subjective/arbitrary and gimmicky reasons the SO kings decide upon.*" ... That's not what any of Slegers's commentary is complaining about. It's mainly about *new users* having their supposedly good questions downvoted, closed and/or deleted for supposedly unfair reasons. And what's wrong with closing popular questions? It's not like they'll be deleted, since they have lots of answers and upvotes.

Comment: I know, that's a common complaint from others.  Tired of arguing... you'll never admit SO has developed a fundamental cultural problem, even if it bites you, so this is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

## Why am I editing questions?

**It's pretty simple, I don't like unformatted code and unnecessary friendliness!**

May the users are too lazy to format or just don't know that there are better ways of showing their work and get more help.

Most of my edits are code format correction
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19658610
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19654375

and removing the redundant friendliness
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19658594

I don't know if anybody cares about the format, but may I can help the helper to understand the problem easier.